# Redirect to Login if user not logged in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

i am new to laravel,

i have code in my controller's __construct like

```
if(Auth::check())
{
    return View::make('view_page');
}

return Redirect::route('login')->withInput()->with('errmessage', 'Please Login to access restricted area.');
```

its working fine, but what i wants is. its really annoying to put these coding in each and every controller, so i wish to put this Verify Auth and redirect to login page in one place, may be in `router.php` or `filters.php`.

I have read some posts in forum as well as in `stackoverflow`, and added code in `filters.php` like below but that's too not working.

```
Route::filter('auth', function() {
    if (Auth::guest())
    return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

#### Laravel 5.4

Use the built in `auth` middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    // your routes
});
```

For a single route:

```
Route::get('profile', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth');
```

[Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication)

#### Laravel 4 (original answer)

That's already built in to laravel. See the `auth` filter in `filters.php`. Just add the before filter to your routes. Preferably use a group and wrap that around your protected routes:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    // your routes

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Or for a single route:

```
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'));
```

To change the redirect URL or send messages along, simply edit the filter in `filters.php` to your liking.

Comment: What does not working mean? You don't get redirected to the login page?

Comment: Yes bro i don't get redirect to login page, also in your code where is redirecting to login page codes?

Comment: That's what the `auth` before filter does. Have you added that filter to the routes?

Comment: its working now Route::get('/dashboard', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'dashboardController@dashboard'));. so adding before => auth will redirects to login :) thanks. and i didn't add Route:group.... in my filter.

Comment: before?? isn;t it middleware now? `Route::group([ 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {`

Comment: @Toskan Yes in the current version of Laravel. This answer is 2 years old and the question is tagged laravel-4.

Comment: Update your answer so it also covers Laravel 5. You'll get more upvotes!

Comment: @lukasgeiter I'm using Laravel 5.4, and It actually does what it's supposed to do, but it now asks the user/password every time I try to access to any route, is there a way to check if the user is logged in and avoid the login form?

Comment: @Lvkz that most likely means the user session is not being persisted.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid code repetition, You can use it in middleware. If you are using the Laravel build in **Auth**, You can directly use the **`auth`** middleware as given,

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
   // define your route, route groups here
});
```

or, for a single route,

```php
Route::get('profile', function () {

})->middleware('auth');
```

If you are building your own, custom Authentication system. You should use the middleware which will check the user is authenticated or not. To create custom middleware, run **`php artisan make:middleware Middelware_Name_Here`** and register the newly created middleware.

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely correct what other people have replied.
This solution is for Laravel 5.4
But just in case, if you have more than one middleware applying to routes, make sure 'auth' middleware comes in the end and not at the start.

Like this:

```
Route::prefix('/admin')->group(function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'CheckUser', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('dashboard','BackendController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
});
```

This entry in the web.php route will take the user [who is not logged in] to the login page if (s)he tries to access a 'protected' URL, "dashboard" in this case.